# How to enable only CTRL+E expansion in Sublime Text Emmet?

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

I want to use [Emmet-sublime](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime) in Sublime Text 3, but I find it annoying that it breaks many of the existing shortcuts. Really, all I want is to be able to manually press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> and have the expansion work.

I know there is the `disabled_keymap_actions` setting, but this is a blacklist. I'd have to go find all the keymap actions, which is a pain. I'd rather have a whitelist, where I could only allow the `expand_abbreviation` command.

**What's the best way of only allowing only <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> and not other emmet shortcuts?**

If the only way is to specify a list via `disabled_keymap_actions`, what is the list I need to use?

**Update**

I found a list at https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/master/misc/generate-keymap.py. But I'm looking more for an `enabled_keymap_actions` setting.

Comment: Taking a short look at the source code you should be able to change the setting to `"disabled_keymap_actions": "all"`. Afterwards just copy the keybindings you want to use and remove/change the context. (E.g. to `{ "key": "selector", "operand": "text.html" }` )

Comment: @r-stein That worked. Good enough for me! Post it as an answer if you want some credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emmet has an option to disable all keys at once, just set the setting to `"disabled_keymap_actions": "all"`. Afterwards you can add your whitelist by copying the corresponding keybindings and remove the emmet context (which blacklists them) and add your selectors instead. You can use `{ "key": "selector", "operand": "text.html" }` to limit the keybinding to html code.

Comment: Thanks! Removing the context was the key for me.